# How to get URL link after creating application shortcut from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, url

Let's say we create an application shortcut for facebook.com and while borwsing the feed, we see some cool news and need to get the URL of the current post.

How can we get the URL when browsing withing a Chrome application shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I too have run into this unexpected hang-up. The only way I have found (so far) is to right-click on the body of the page and choose `View page source`. That should open the page in a fresh Chrome window, with the URL at the top, preceded by `view-source:`

Not super convenient or intuitive perhaps, but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac, you could probably use [this keyboard shortcut](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en):

```
⌘-Option-C     Copies the URL of the page you're viewing to the clipboard.
```

I couldn't find a similar shortcut for Windows, but if you aren't averse to using a quick and dirty solution, try this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Make sure the **Headers and footers** option is checked in the print options.
   [image: Headers and footers]
3. Select and copy the page URL as it appears in the tiny little footer in print preview
   [image: Page URL in footer]